# How to pass argument to callback and don't lose bind?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, argument-passing

I have the following code:

```
$.getJSON('getAllTerminals.json', renderTerminalsOnMapAndFitBounds.bind({index:globalRequestCounter++, navigateToTypedText:true}))

...
function renderTerminalsOnMapAndFitBounds(data, updateSelectedTerminals) {
        renderTerminalsOnMap.call(this,data);
        fitBounds();
        if(this.navigateToTypedText === true){
            navigateMapToTypedAdress();
        }
        if (updateSelectedTerminals) {
            $.getJSON('getSelectedTerminals', {}, function (json) {
                window.MARC.addTerminalPage.terminalsSelected = json;
                update();
                initPage();
            });
        }
    }
```

Can you advise me how to make that all works as now but to `renderTerminalsOnMapAndFitBounds` was passed `updateSelectedTerminals` as true ?

Comment: Sometimes an anonymous function makes things so much simpler.

Comment: @adeneo it is existing working code and I want to make minimal code correction without global refactoring

Comment: @gstackoverflow: No global refactoring needed. See Bergi's answer to see what adeneo means by using an anonymous function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use `bind` to partially apply non-initial parameters (and there's no `flip`). Just use a function expression:

```
$.getJSON('getAllTerminals.json', function(data) {
    renderTerminalsOnMapAndFitBounds.call({
        index:globalRequestCounter++,
        navigateToTypedText:true
    }, data, true);
});
```

If you have to use bind, either change the parameter order of `renderTerminalsOnMapAndFitBounds`, or make it accept that `updateSelectedTerminals` parameter as a property of the `this` object.

Comment: You can use Underscore's [partial](http://underscorejs.org/#partial) to to partially apply non-initial parameters though.

Comment: @mAAdhaTTah: Yes, of course you can use whatever kind of helper functions you like :-) I was just refering to the builtins.

Comment: No worries, comment was just in case OP wasn't aware of them.